# oracle sql statement help to query against multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, subquery, inner-join

I am struggling with a sql statement. I am hoping a guru can help a beginner out, currently I have multiple select in statements.. but think there is a better way as I have been stuck.

Below are the tables and pertinent columns in each table

```
country
 -country_id
barcodes_banned_in_country
 -barcode(varchar)
 -country_id
 -country_name
orders
 -order_id
 -country_name
item
  -order_id
  -item_id
  -barcode(varchar)
```

The goal is to get all orders that are banned based off the barcode banned list.
Any help with this sql statement would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have `orders.country_name` rather than use `country_id`? And why is `country_id` not in the `country` table as its primary key?

Comment: country_id is the primary key in the country table, and unfortunately can't add country_id to the orders table right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses `exists`:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where exists (
    select 1
    from barcodes_banned_in_country bic
    inner join item i on i.barcode = bic.barcode
    where i.order_id = o.order_id and bic.country_name = o.country_name
)
```

This brings all orders whose at least one item have a barcode that is banned in the order's country.

If, on the other hand, you want the list of the banned barcodes per order, then you can join and aggregate:

```
select o.order_id, o.country_name, listagg(i.barcode, ',') banned_barcodes
from orders o
inner join item i 
    on  i.order_id = o.order_id
inner join barcodes_banned_in_country bic 
    on  i.barcode = bic.barcode 
    and bic.country_name = o.country_name
group by o.order_id, o.country_name
```

Note that, as commented by MT0, you should really be storing the id of the country in `orders` rather than the country name. Accordingly, you wouldn't need the country name in the banned barcodes table.